# Logging incoming requests in BotBuilder

Tags: node.js, facebook, botframework

Trying to log all incoming requests from Facebook so I can inspect the object I get back to do some stuff with the built in NLP Facebooks implemented.

I, however, can't seem to find anywhere where it tells me I can `console.log` incoming requests.

in the `server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());` method I'm trying to pass in a `console.log` but nothing happens.

```
const express = require('express');
const builder = require('botbuilder');

const server = express();

const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
  appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
  appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD,
});

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log('Running on port 5000');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use middleware to access to the incoming/outgoing messages.

Take a look at the [Middleware and Logging with BotBuilder Node SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/capability-middlewareLogging) sample.

**Capturing User Input**

```
  botbuilder: function (session, next) {
       console.log(session.message.text);
       next();
   }
```

**Capturing bot output to a user**

```
send: function (event, next) {
    console.log(event.text);
    next();
}
```

In particular, since you want to check things coming from `Facebook`, you might have to log the `sourceEvent` property, which is where channels send their native information.

Comment: this gets called before I know the intent, is there any middleware that gets triggered after the intent?