# Intercept user intent with `routing` middleware

Tags: node.js, botframework, dialogflow-es, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to intercept messages to send to my analytics server.

I'm looking to send it some data such as: `messages`,`intent`,`resulted dialog`.

I tried to use the `routing` middleware of `universalBot` in this fashion:

`bot.on('routing',(session)=>{
    console.log(session.intent);
    console.log(session);
})`

But it seems like the intent is `undefined`, and the only way I manage to see it is through `triggerAction` => `onFindAction` function.

I can use this method but it seems like a hack, is there a good way to intercept the intent data with middleware?

I'm using the Node.js SDK with `botbuilder-apiai`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging incoming requests in BotBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592351/logging-incoming-requests-in-botbuilder)

Comment: It is not, as the intent is not coming from facebook - but from api.ai